# Restoring Apache Tomcat after an accidental delete

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a server running apache tomcat. The path to the server is following:

```
root@serverb:/usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23# pwd
/usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23
root@serverb:/usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23# ls
LICENSE  NOTICE  RELEASE-NOTES  RUNNING.txt  bin  conf  lib  logs  temp  webapps  work  ws.war
```

From time to time, I have to go `logs/` folder and run following command:

```
find . -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
```

However, I accidentally ran this command in `/usr/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23` as a result, my `ws.war` file and other files from within `bin/` folder got deleted.

I have the backup of **ws.war** but not of the **apache folder**. Is there anyway I can reinstall the apache and restore my server.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're not asking how to create a backup after you need it (not before...), right?

Of course, you can get tomcat at http://tomcat.apache.org, but if you don't have your configuration and changed settings (e.g. memory settings, host setup etc.) you'll have to redo it from memory or until nobody complains any more.

Congratulations, you've learnt about the importance of backups. When you're done with the new installation, consider having a proper backup from now on. Keep in mind: IMHO you're only allowed to call something a backup if you have demonstrated that you can use it to restore to a new environment in the time that you specify as acceptable downtime.